# How to Convert CAPICOM to .NET equivalent

Tags: vb.net, encryption, capicom

This is the code from my VB6 app using CAPICOM

```
Set ed = New EncryptedData
ed.Algorithm = CAPICOM_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM_3DES
ed.SetSecret mySecret, CAPICOM_SECRET_PASSWORD
ed.Content = myText
myResult = ed.Encrypt(CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY)
```

but I need to convert the same functionality to VB.NET.  Is there an equivalent to get the same values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, look at the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) namespace. You'll find relevant classes there, include the [TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c88cew86%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Why is this considered a complete/accepted answer?  It's EASY to find the classes, but how do you ensure that the 3DES IV and Key are initialized in the .NET equivalent code to decrypt a value previously encrypted in VB6?

Comment: @KrisOye: The question was vague, so the answer is broad.

Answer (score 1):

I went down this road, too.  I made various attempts to decrypt data from VB6/CAPICOM using the crypto namespaces James mentioned above (without any luck).

According to the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382010(v=vs.85).aspx), I am given the impression it is not possible to migrate your code to anything other than a P/Invoke call to the CAPI library.  If you find yourself doing this, you might be better served creating a migration tool that decrypts using CAPI and then encrypts/exports the data using an open standard (sounds like CAPI is/will be deprecated).